# In android, how can I make an app that is communicating between user and app by using tts, stt?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I am trying to make an app like "Siri", IOS.

So I used tts, stt sample code.

```
private ArrayList<String> result = null;
...
private void speakOut(String text) {
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null);
}

  private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

tts works very well. 
stt also works well when It starts alone.
But the problem is that if I make the code to communicate app, like

```
 public void onClick(View v){
    speakOut("How can I help you?");
    promptSpeechInput();
    String voiceInputData = result.get(0);

    if (voiceInputData.equals("hello")){
        Log.d("debug", "hello spoken.");
    }
    else{
        Log.d("debug", "nothing.");
    }
}
```

result : "nothing."

It doesn't work well. So I debugged. Then I found that the code doesn't work sequentially. If I call promptSpeechInput(), then while I speak something, the main code already works next line(e.g, if statement). So I can't make the code as I think.

So. can anybody know how to solve this problem?
I mean, I want to make a method

promptSpeechInput() ---> whenever I call this method, after I speak something, the string lies in "result" variable.

And also the code must work step by step So that onClick() method can work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TTS is asynchronous.  IT invokes an activity in another app.  When its done, it calls onActivityResult.  Any code that needs the result needs to be called from there.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to know is about stt, not tts.

Comment: Sorry, I typoed, I meant STT.  You see in your code where you have startActivity?  That means its going to be calling out to another program asynchronously.  STT is extremely complicated, and usually involves sending the speech to a server for processing.  You need to handle the asynchronous result, there is no way to return one synchronously.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!!